# Accidently pressed Y on mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

Hello Blender community.
I was working on something when I accidently pressed <kbd>Y</kbd> with a part of mesh selected, and now that part is not with the mesh anymore and can move around freely. I didn't notice this when working on it so can't do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> anymore.
Is there any way to.. attach the parts again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You didn't move that part yet, select all in edit mode, press W and choose Remove Doubles.

Comment: thx man, this fixed it for me

Comment: However, when I try to solidify it, the textures go like inside the mesh, anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: Press CTRL+N to recalculate normals. That should fix it. If that's not because of normals, it's possible, that one or more vertices of the loose part didn't merge with the rest, cause was to far. If this is the case, check which one would that be and merge vertices by selecting the one from loose part and then the one from the rest of mesh and Alt+M and choose At last.